# Can I create conditions for regression coefficients in something like nls() or nnls()?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have recently been playing around with R's regression functions/packages. I'm wondering, is there a way that I could force my regression coefficients to sum to a particular value? I understand that forcing the coefficients might create a poor fit, but nevertheless I'm looking for a way to do it.

Sorry, I don't have much code as I have had no success doing this, but I'm trying for something like this:

```
b
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    6
[3,]    4
[4,]    7
[5,]    8

A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
[2,]    7    5    5
[3,]    5    5    3
[4,]    7    8    9
[5,]    8    9    9
```

I want a function to create a model for b using A

> constrainedcoefs <- function(A, b, coefsum) {
>
> fit <- nnls(A, b)

Ideally with

```
sum(coef(fit)) = coefsum
```

Does anyone know of a way to force the sum of coef(fit) to be some user defined value? Or of a package with this feature. I have only found packages that let me define upper and lower bounds and some discussion on ways that gets coef(fit) = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have input data like

```
dd <- structure(list(b = c(2L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 8L), A1 = c(2L, 7L, 5L, 
7L, 8L), A2 = c(3L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 9L), A3 = c(4L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 9L
)), .Names = c("b", "A1", "A2", "A3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

You could try using `nls` with

```
nls(b~a1*A1+a2*A2+(1-a1-a2)*A3, dd, 
    lower=0, upper=1,algorithm="port", 
    start=c(a1=.3, a2=.3))
```

Here we require them to sum to 1 so we really only have two free parameters. Once we know `a1` and `a2` we can figure out `a3`. Then we use the "port" algorithm which allows us to specify upper and lower bounds to make sure the values don't go below 0 or above 1. WIth this data I got

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: b ~ a1 * A1 + a2 * A2 + (1 - a1 - a2) * A3
   data: dd
    a1     a2 
0.7647 0.0000 
 residual sum-of-squares: 1.059
```

So the parameters are  (0.7647, 0.0000, 0.2353)

Of course, this type of regression seems very unusual so be very careful about the inferences you make based on model fit.

Comment: Thanks! This is very close to what I'm looking for I think. The part of the line in the nls(), a1*A1+a2*A2+(1-a1-a2)*A3, is very specific to a dd with only three columns. What if I wanted to feed nls() a dd of arbitrary size, requiring some arbitrary number of coefficients?

Comment: Then you will need to dynamically build your formula and coefficient initialization vector.